# Как проверить, для всех ли элементов листа выполняется одно из условий

Tags: java

Получаю следующее значение:
`List <String> list = [kz, kz, kz, kg, ru, ru, ua, ru, ru, ru, ru, ru, ru, ru, kg]`

Необходимо проверить принимает ли каждый элемент одно из значений: ru, kg, kz, cz.
Если попадается другое (не из этого списка), то выводить False (например).

Хотела воспользоваться стримом, но не могу вставить больше одного условия, например `ru`:
`var correctCodes = list.stream().allMatch((s) -> s.contains("ru"));`

Не могу придумать, как реализовать нужную проверку.

Comment: ``var correctCodes`` - это не ява.

Comment: @Эникейщик, с одиннадцатой вроде можно так.

Comment: Напишите так https://stackoverflow.com/a/18044548/7485582

Comment: `.allMatch((s) -> s.contains("ru") || s.contains("kz") || s.contains("kg"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> list = List.of("kz", "kz", "kz", "kg", "ru", "ru", "ua",
            "ru", "ru", "ru", "ru", "ru", "ru", "ru", "kg");
Set<String> checkWords = Set.of("ru", "kg", "kz", "cz");
var correctCodes = list.stream().allMatch(s -> checkWords.contains(s));
System.out.println(correctCodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант

```
если (элемент != ру и элемент != кз итд):
{принт фалсе}
```

Второй вариант:

```
switch element 
    case ru:
    case kz:
    Итд:
        Что-то делать
        break
    default: 
        print false
        break
```